# Why is WCF client configuration different when running under the VS2015 debugger?

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

In my WCF client code I add a message inspector (using an IEndpointBehavior).

```
class MyBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new MyMessageInspector());
    }
}

public class MyMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name));
    }
}
```

Now here comes the part I do not understand:

- When I make a WCF call using a proxy configured to use this behavior, the following happens:

  - If the call is made from a process running inside the VS2015 debugger, `True` is printed to the console, meaning `request.Properties["httpRequest"]` is present.
  - If the call is made from a process running normally (not in the debugger), `False` is printed to the console.

Why is WCF configured differently when running inside/outside the VS2015 debugger? How does this happen? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209220/property-httprequest-not-present "Apparently, when you run in the debugger, something it does initializes the HttpRequestMessageProperty, but when you run in a regular runtime environment, this Message property does not get initialized."

Comment: Is it something to do with the IIS Express host that is being used by VS?  I assume you are publishing it to IIS full?  I am just guessing...

Comment: @DomCotton This is a WCF client, a console app, so service hosting is not the issue here